# Round function Forces Scientific Notation Instead of Decimal

Tags: decimal, rounding, libreoffice-calc, scientific-notation, libreoffice-basic

I've run into an issue with the ROUND function in Basic for LibreOffice:

```
Function Round(dNumber As Double, iDecimals As Integer) As Variant
    Dim oRound As Object
    Dim vArgs(1 to 2) As Variant

    oRound = createUnoService("com.sun.star.sheet.FunctionAccess")

    vArgs(1) = dNumber
    vArgs(2) = iDecimals

    Round = oRound.callFunction("round", vArgs())
End Function
```

It returns Scientific Notation on dNumber values that are less than 0.1 instead of the rounded decimal value that's expected.

**EXAMPLE:**
    msgbox(Round(0.0333333, 2))

Results in:
3E-02.00
instead of the expected: 0.03

Can anyone tell me why this is occuring and if the solution that I've written below is the correct way of getting around the problem or if there's a better way?

```
Function Round(dNumber As Double, iDecimals As Integer) As Variant
    Dim oRound As Object 'Round function object
    Dim dCompNumber As Double 'Store the Compensated value of dNumber 
    Dim dResult As Double 'Result of the rounding to be passed
    Dim vArgs(1 to 2) As Variant 'Arguments: Number to be rounded, Number of decimal places

    dCompNumber = dNumber 'Copy dNumber

    oRound = createUnoService("com.sun.star.sheet.FunctionAccess")
    'Get access to the library that contains the Round() function

    'Compensate for Scientific Notation that occurs with numbers less than 0.1
    If dNumber < 0.1 Then dCompNumber = dNumber + 1 ' Add 1 to temporarily increase value > 0.1 

    vArgs(1) = dCompNumber
    vArgs(2) = iDecimals

    dResult = oRound.callFunction("round", vArgs())

    'Remove the Compensation for Scientific Notation
    If dNumber < 0.1 Then dResult = dResult - 1 'Subtract 1 from the temporary value so that it is back to < 0.1 

    Round = dResult
End Function
```

[Screenshot of simplified `Round()` function using `Msgbox()` to output the result of **3E-02** in Scientific Notation instead of the expected result of **0.03** in decimal.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9acvJ.png)

Comment: `Round` is not a good name for your function because that is the same as the built-in function.

Answer (score 0):

The preferred way to round in LibreOffice Basic is described at https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=66808.

```vb
Function MyRound(dNumber As Double, iDecimals As Integer) As Double
   MyRound = Int(dNumber * 10 ^ iDecimals + 0.5) / 10 ^ iDecimals
End Function
```

Entering `=MYROUND(1/3,5)` in the spreadsheet produces `0.33333`.